# How to obtain row for minimum date for a value that is equal to the value in maximum date, per group?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to obtain row for a query.. where row value1, value2 in minimum end_date is equal to the max end_date, per group of id's.

My current query only obtains the row value1, value2 from the max end_date in the query result:

```
select a.id, a.end_date, a.value1, a.value2
from table1 as a
inner join (
    select id, max(end_date) as end_date
    from database1
    group by id
) as b 
on a.id = b.id and a.end_date = b.end_date
order by id, end_date
```

This result obtains the most recent record, but I'm looking to obtain the row where value1 & value2 in min(end_date = max(end_date), grouped by id.

Here is an example query detailing what I want to obtain:

| id | end_date | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 02/12/22 | 2 | 1 |
| AAPL | 02/13/22 | 2 | 1 |
| AAPL | 02/14/22 | 3 | 2 |
| AAPL | 02/15/22 | 3 | 2 |
| MSFT | 03/01/22 | 2 | 5 |
| MSFT | 03/02/22 | 4 | 5 |
| MSFT | 03/03/22 | 4 | 5 |
| MSFT | 03/04/22 | 4 | 5 |

From this previous query, the query that I need to obtain is the following:

| id | end_date | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 02/14/22 | 3 | 2 |
| MSFT | 03/02/22 | 4 | 5 |

So once again, I need the row where value1, value2 in min(end_date) = max(end_date), grouped by id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with row_number()

```
select id, end_date, value1, value2
from (
   select t1.*, row_number() over(partition by t1.id order by t1.end_date) rn
   from tbl t1
   join (
     select id, end_date, value1, value2
     from (
       select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by end_date desc) rn
       from tbl t
     ) t
     where rn = 1
   ) t2 on t1.id = t2.id and t1.value1 = t2.value1 and t1.value2 = t2.value2 
) t
where rn = 1
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=efd3448ec7701c25d195bca2a5cba596)

Comment: Hello, thank you providing solution!  I realized that its supposed to run Oracle 11g Release 2, doesn't seem to run.

Comment: Oracle wants an explicit table name/alias when * is combined with other expressions. See the edited answer

Comment: To clarify the comment below,  (id, value1, value2) is not unique. Does this affect the query result?

Comment: I added a small correction near the end of the code, where we join t1 and t2 on:
t1.id = t2.id and t1.value1 = t2.value1 and t1.value2 = t2.value2
This is because id with the same value1 and value2 in their records would mix up.

Comment: @aeon, the answer is corrected.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `distinct on` twice, once `on(id, value1, value2)` in a derived table to get rows when (value1, value2) changes, then in the outer query `on(id)` to get the row where there is the last change on (value1, value2):

```
select distinct on(id) * from
(select distinct on(id, value1, value2) id, end_date, value1, value2
from table1
order by id, value1, value2, end_date) t
order by id, end_date desc;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9ddc7e816107b91d6abeceb902d0eb25)

Comment: What if Value1 is not odered the same way as end_date ? [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=4f5da92f319e9de1eff5c026a383edba)

Comment: @Serg you're right. Will have to ask the OP if (id, value1, value2) is unique or not.